common folder with template files for gitlab python projects
I have a folder with word templates files which are common for several projects.
If template was changed, i have to copy new file to all that projects in that directory.
Is there a way to automate the procedure?
I thought about creating a diff project "word_templates" and make changes in the project only. But how can I force another project "my_project" to update the folder with files from "word_templates" ?

No way to automate. Whatever solution you gonna use — file copying, submodules, subtrees — you will need to manually update all projects, commit and push. Submodules and subtrees are a little bit simpler to update but they have their own quirks, esp. submodules — they certainly have a lot of quirks in regard to branch switching, merge and multi-worktrees workflows.

I think the best way is to move templates folder to stand alone repository and use them as git submodule. In this case you'll have X projects which include 1 dependency. During the development process, you will be able to update only templates without switching branches of a separate project. Something like:
$ cd project_dir     # project repository
$ cd word_templates  # templates repository
$ git pull           # pull latest templates


much appreciate for pointing on git_submodule!

Submodule is hardly an automation. Superproject (the parent repo) remembers submodules' commit so if a submodule was updated all superprojects need to pull the submodule and commit the change. No automation, so what gives?

@phd I don't quite understand what difference it makes who the parent is. You can set up a folder update on all hosts when a new version of the templates is released. I don't see any difficulty in automation. 1 button - update templates on all hosts or on specific ones

I do not understand how do you suggest to automatically update all superprojects when a submodule was updated. Could you elaborate? A repository doesn't know what repositories use it as a submodule so it cannot automatically update all its superprojects. This means all superprojects must be manually updated, committed and pushed. Where is automation?

@phd what difference does it make if it's a submodule or not? it's the same as a regular button in a separate project that generates templates on hosts. or regular ansible playbook - doesn't matter.

Yes, exactly that — no automation. So submodules are not much better than any other solution (manual copying, subtrees) and have a lot of their own quirks.

@phd you can copy files manually to X hosts if you like... please don't bother me anymore. good luck

No need to bother you anymore because the bottom line — no automation — was already resolved. And you have forgotten to warn the OP about submodules quirks, so I did that. Good luck!

I have no idea who is giving me down votes. If you don't know how to make a gitlab action that synchronizes one folder after tests, then just google it. This has nothing to do with submodules. The answer says DURING THE DEV PROCESS
